# Custom Delimiter using pyparsing

Tags: python-2.7, pyparsing

I'm trying to write a parser for some text. What am I doing wrong?
consider the following pyparsing code

```
from pyparsing import CaselessLiteral,StringEnd,Suppress,alphanums,alphas,alphas,
Word,ParseException,ParseResults,nums,Group,ZeroOrMore,ParseElement,restOfline,Combine,Optional,Literal,LineEnd
ParseElement.enablePackrat()
import lxml.etree

#define common syntax
delimiter=Supress("->")|Suppress(">")
line_ending=";"
cust_seperator="_"
cust_code=Word(alphanums)
description=Word(alphanums+"~#!@£$%^&*()'-+/{}[]=. ")
limit_state=CaselessLiteral("REACHED")|CaselessLiteral("NOT_REACHED")|CaselessLiteral("RETIRED")


#define grammar for user comment
StringStart=CaselessLiteral("COMMENT")
comment_text=Word(alphanums+"#!@£$%^&*()<>'/{}[]=. ")
usercomment_syntax=(StringStart+delimiter+comment_text+line_ending).setResultsNmae('user_comment')

#define grammar for upperlimit
StringStart=CaselessLiteral("CUSTOMER_LIMIT_REACHED")
cust_code_prefix=Word(alphanums,max=6)
customer_identifier=Combine(cust_code_prefix+Optional(cust_seperator)+cust_code+Optional(description))
customerupperlimit=(StringStart+delimiter+customer_identifier+delimiter+limit_state+line_ending).setResultsNmae('customer_upper_limit')
```

So consider the following

> COMMENT->Welcome to bank one;

This passes and the tokens are ['COMMENT','Welcome to bank one',';']

> ```
> CUSTOMER_LIMIT_REACHED->1234_A0001 [Harry mop]->NOT_REACHED;
> ```

This passes and the tokens are

> ['CUSTOMER_LIMIT_REACHED','1234_A0001 [Harry mop]','NOT_REACHED',';']

But what happens when a > is in the "wrong" place?

> ```
> CUSTOMER_LIMIT_REACHED->1234_A0001 [Sally >12 top]->NOT_REACHED;
> ```

This doesn't seem to work for me the appearance of > in the description causes an error. So redefining the description like so

> description=Word(alphanums+"~#!@£$%^&*()'-+/{}[]=.> ")

Should work, but then it breaks the comment syntax. 
I just want to have the delimiter -> be treated as one

Thinking about it I don't think

```
delimiter=Suppress("->")| Suppress(">")
```

is correct surely I only need

```
delimiter=Suppress("->")
```

Thanks, @Paul. I have tried your suggestion.

```
description = Combine(OneOrMore(Word(alphanums+"~#!@£$%^&*()'+/{}[]=. >") + ('-' + ~FollowedBy('>'))))
```

I don't know if I am typing something wrong but breaking out the hyphen has proved a little tricky

> ```
> CUSTOMER_LIMIT_REACHED->1234_A0001 [Harry-mop]->NOT_REACHED;
> ```

now failed, if I am right I believe that

> - ('-' + ~FollowedBy('>')
>     will expect a hyphen (-) to appear after the word, as in it MUST, so
>
>   CUSTOMER_LIMIT_REACHED->1234_A0001 [Harry-mop]->NOT_REACHED;
>     failed but
>     CUSTOMER_LIMIT_REACHED->1234_A0001 [Harry-mop]-->NOT_REACHED;
>     passes.

I tweaked the answer just a little after some experimentation to

```
description = Combine(OneOrMore(Word(alphanums+"~#!@£$%^&*()'+/{}[]=. >") + Optional('-' + ~FollowedBy('>'))))
```

Thanks for getting me on the right path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the issue is with

```
description=Word(alphanums+"~#!@£$%^&*()'-+/{}[]=. ")
```

If you add '>' to this set of allowed characters in `description`, pyparsing will not be able to distinguish a '->' that is part of the description vs. a '->' that is the delimiter (since both '-' and '>' are included in the set of allowed characters).

You will need to implement a negative lookahead so that '-' or '>' alone will be acceptable contents for descriptions. However, within the token-building of Word's, there is no way to do this. You'll need to break out '-' (as the leading character in '->') as a separate thing.

```
description = (OneOrMore(Word(alphanums+"~#!@£$%^&*()'+/{}[]=. >") + 
                  ('-' + ~FollowedBy('>'))))
```

Wrap this whole thing in a Combine so that pyparsing will not give separate strings for the separate bits of this description:

```
description = Combine(OneOrMore(Word(alphanums+"~#!@£$%^&*()'+/{}[]=. >") + 
                  ('-' + ~FollowedBy('>'))))
```

At this point, `delimiter = Suppress('->')` should be sufficient.